# my create voice channel command doesn't work, I do not understand why it doesn't recognize "execute", how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, discord.js

here's is the code and error message
it is not working only for the create voice channel command, everything elses works.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
module.exports = {
    name: 'createtextchannel',
    description: "this is a command!",
    execute(message, args){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the `MANAGE_CHANNELS` permission.');
        let channelName = args.slice(0).join(' '); 
        message.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
                type: "voice", 
              })
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6HRN.png
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have a command with name: "createvoicechannel"?
In the code you posted, the `name: ""` is something else.
`"Cannot read property of undefined"` means that `.get('createvoicechannel')` returns undefined, therefore there is no `.execute` method to call.

Comment: you were right lol, i forgot to rename the voice command